# Adding LoF and LoT page number in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

LoF, LoT, Abstract and list of the publication, etc page number are not appearing in TOC. Kindly help..

```
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph} 

\addToPDFBookmarks{0}{Front Matter}{rootNode} 

\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{TitlePage}{a} 
\include{front-matter/TitlePage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{CertificateofApproval}{b} 
\include{front-matter/CertificateofApproval} 

\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{copyright}{c} 
\include{front-matter/copyright} 

\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Acknowledgments}{d} 
\include{front-matter/acknowledgments} 

\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Dedication}{e} 
\include{front-matter/dedication} 

\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Abstract}{f} 
\include{front-matter/abstract}

\tableofcontents 
\include{front-matter/Publications}
\include{front-matter/nomenclature}
\listoftables 
\listoffigures



\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

[image]

Comment: Which documentclass do you use?  Maybe you can load package `tocbibind` for entries of LoF, LoT and Bibliography in ToC.

Comment: Thank you esdd.  By using tocbibind package now LoF and LoT are appearing. But still abstract and list of publication page number is missing. Further its  also giving the ToC page number as well and dotted lines are missing. i am using utthesis dissertation class.

Comment: To remove the ToC from ToC use option `nottoc`: `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`. If your LoF and LoT are chapters in a book or report class or sections in an article class their ToC entry will be formated like the other chapter or section entries. To answer your other question a real minimal *working* example is needed.

Comment: \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} worked perfectly. The last thing i would like to know that how we can add abstract and list of publications etc page no in ToC. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your last comment.

LaTeX provides the `\addcontentsline{<file>}{<kind>}{<text>}` macro which adds an entry to `<file>` (typically `toc` or `lof` or `lot`) for Table of Contents, List of Figures
or List of Tables; where `<kind>` is the name of a sectional division (e.g., chapter, subsection) for the ToC or figure or table for the List of ...s; and `<text>` is the title.

So, if you have an unnumbered chapter called, say, Abstract:

```
...
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
% text of the abstract
```

will put the title Abstract and the page number in the ToC formatted as a chapter entry.

This is described in more detail in the `tocloft` (`> texdoc tocloft`) package which can also be used for the other parts of your question.

To get the LoF and LoT listed in the ToC (assuming they are only on one page, if not use `tocbibind`):

```
...
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
...
```

Comment: Thank you Peter .

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Wilson told, by adding the following code, page number of Abstract will appear in ToC

`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}`

Further, if someone faces the wrong page number of Abstract add the following code:

```
\clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include{front-matter/Abstract}
```

Comment: Better to put the `\addcontentsline..` after the chapter heading in the included Abstract file, then it will refer to the actual page number.

Comment: Thanks Peter Wilson